# Add save/commit button to custom feature from

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to add a save/commit button to a custom QGIS feature from. This is very helpful when there is a linked table dispayed on the same form - the link will work only once the main table has been saved.

The form should look something like this:

[image: Custom form]

Which function should I call for the save/refresh button?

---

After some research, I found the following solution (which is quite clumsy!)

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

myDialog = None

def formOpen(dialog, QGIS_vector_layer, featureid):
    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog

    global ly 
    ly= QGIS_vector_layer #this is a QGIS layer object, not a layer ID

    # Connect a signal
    Refresh_button = dialog.findChild(QPushButton,"Cmd_refresh")  
    Refresh_button.clicked.connect(refresh)

def refresh():

    myDialog.accept() #step 1 dump data into editing buffer
    ly.commitChanges() #step 2 save (but this closes the editing mode!)
    ly.startEditing() #step 3 re-open for editing
```

This works, but it is still not the best method. The form is not emptied from the data entred, which means that each time we hit either refresh or OK button, a new record will be added. But that would be another problem.